# How can I convert a 7 bit 2s complement number into a decimal number?

Tags: digital-logic

If I have a number like this

1111011

I can't tell whether it is a positive or negative number, but all I know is that it is a 2s complement of something and I have to find the decimal equivalent number.

How can I convert this 7bit twos complement without knowing its sign bit to the decimal?

Comment: the sign bit is clearly visible

Comment: `I have to find the decimal equivalent number` by what means? "Logical" gates? MCU program?

Comment: You have to know if that 7-bit number includes the sign bit or not, otherwise you can't know how to interpret it in any way what it represents and it's just bits without meaning.

Comment: Please clarify whether this is the complete number _including_ the sign bit or not. Then do some research on two's complement (like [on the Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)) to learn how to interpret the number. You might want to [edit] your question to show your progress, and which detail is left to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that this is a full word of 7-bit, that it is twos-complement (that it is ***not*** an 8-bit twos-complement value where you've taken only the least significant 7 bits), then you know it is negative because of the upper bit's value as '1'.

I'll document the algorithm and use a different value for the purposes of being concrete about applying the algorithm.

1. 1101110: Starting value is this 7-bit twos-complement
2. 0010001: If upper bit is '1', convert the number to its positive magnitude by first complementing every bit (turn 0's to 1's and 1's to 0's.)
3. 021: Divide the result into groups of three bits to form octal notation.
4. .21: Remove any prefixed '0' and then prefix with the radix "."
5. 2.1: Move the radix to the right by one position.
6. 4: Double the value to the left of the radix, as though it were a decimal number.
7. 21.: Move the radix to the right by one position.
8. 17.: Subtract the doubled value, decimally, from the value from step 8 with the radix aligned.
9. If there are more digits to the right of the radix, then go to step 5.
10. -18: If step 2 complemented the bits, then add 1 to the result and prefix a '-' as the number was negative.

So the decimal value is -18, in this example case.

Now apply the same idea to your value.

Throughout the process, the value to the left of the radix is in decimal notation and the value to the right of the radix is in octal.

Let's assume a larger and more complicated negative twos complement 14-bit value: 10110011001001.

Note sign is (-). Complement it to form 01001100110110. Convert to octal: 11466. Place radix: 1.1466. Double 1. to make 2. Move radix to right: 11.466. Subtract 2. from 11.466 to create 9.466. Double 9. to make 18. Move radix right: 94.66. Subtract 18. from 94.66 to create 76.66. Double 76. to make 152. Move radix right: 766.6. Subtract 152. from 766.6 to create 614.6. Double 614. to make 1228. Move radix right: 6146. Subtract 1228. from 6146. to create 4918. No more non-zero digits to the right, so terminate algorithm after adding 1 and prefixing the negative sign. Result is -4919.

---

Assuming you already have an unsigned octal value, the algorithm is a little simpler to write out:

```
CONVERSION OF OCTAL TO DECIMAL

  (0) Prefix the number with "0."  Be sure to include
      the radix point.  It's an important marker.

  (1) Double the value to the left side of the radix,
      using decimal rules, move the radix point one digit
      rightward, and then place this doubled value
      underneath the current value so that the radix
      points align.

  (2) Subtract decimally those digits to the left of
      the radix and simply drop down those digits to
      the right, without modification.

  (3) If digits remain to the right of the radix, goto 1.
```

For example, converting octal 11466 to decimal:

```
 0.1 1 4 6 6      octal value
  -0
 -----------
   1.1 4 6 6
  -  2
  ----------
     9.4 6 6
  -  1 8
  ----------
     7 6.6 6
  -  1 5 2
  ----------
     6 1 4.6
  -  1 2 2 8
  ----------
     4 9 1 8.     decimal value
```

The reverse process is also readily given:

```
CONVERSION OF DECIMAL TO OCTAL

  (0) Prefix the number with "0."  Be sure to include
      the radix point.  It's an important marker.

  (1) Double the value to the left side of the radix,
      using octal rules, move the radix point one digit
      rightward, and then place this doubled value
      underneath the current value so that the radix
      points align.

  (2) If the moved radix point crosses over a digit
      that is 8 or 9, convert it to 0 or 1 and add
      the carry to the next leftward digit of the
      current value.

  (3) Add octally those digits to the left of the radix
      and simply drop down those digits to the right,
      without modification.

  (4) If digits remain to the right of the radix, goto 1.
```

For example, converting decimal 4918 to octal:

```
 0.4 9 1 8        decimal value
  +0
 ---------
   4.9 1 8
  +1 0
  --------
   6 1.1 8
  +1 4 2
  --------
   7 5 3.8
  +1 7 2 6
  --------
 1 1 4 6 6.       octal value
```

The challenge question would be to explain the theory by which the above works!